# ggplot scale_fill_gradient2 "stopping" at midpoint

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been asking a lot of questions about maps here...thanks in advance for all the help.

I've been producing maps of covid infection data.  Basic plot code looks like

```
p <- ne_pop_counties_cov %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = infRate, geometry=geometry), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = ne_states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +   
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Population \nInfected", trans = "log",low='green', high='red',
                      breaks=c(0, round(max(ne_pop_counties_cov$infRate),2))) +
  geom_point(data=neBases, aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1,size=personnel), color = "hotpink") +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(size='AFMC \nMil + Civ') +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", 
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
a <- p + transition_time(infected) + 
  labs(title='Confirmed COVID-19 Cases: {frame_time}',
       subtitle='HQ AFMC/A9A \nData: usafacts.org')
```

I was asked to modify the color scale and tried using scale_fill_gradient2 to add a midpoint color

```
p <- ne_pop_counties_cov %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = infRate, geometry=geometry), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = ne_states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +   
  #scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Population \nInfected", trans = "log",low='green', high='red',
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "% Population \nInfected", trans = "log",low='navajowhite', mid='red', 
                      high='navyblue',
                      na.value = "white",
                      midpoint = max(ne_pop_counties_cov$infRate)/2,
                      breaks=c(0, round(max(ne_pop_counties_cov$infRate),2))) +
  geom_point(data=neBases, aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1,size=personnel), color = "hotpink") +
  #geom_label_repel(data=AFMCbases, aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1, label=Base)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(size='AFMC \nMil + Civ') +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", 
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
a <- p + transition_time(infected) + 
  labs(title='Confirmed COVID-19 Cases: {frame_time}',
       subtitle='HQ AFMC/A9A \nData: usafacts.org')
```

which should, if I understand it have a low color of navajowhite, a mid of red, and a high of navy blue.  But this is the map I get

[image]

No matter what I do with the value of midpoint I get a map whose scale uses red for the max...

Probably doing something very basic wrong.

Edit: it was suggested I remove the log transform....doing so produces this map

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using a color palette instead of the ggplot geom. library(RColorBrewer) aswell as library(viridis) are famous ones

Comment: Unfortunately my boss has seen another map he likes where the color scale roughly matches those three...now I'm supposed to replicate it

Comment: check    show_col(c("#ffdead","#ff0000","#000080"))  aswell as:  show_col(viridis_pal(option = "magma")(8))    second example is magma from viridis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `trans = log`. When your data is too skewed, perform a log transform of the data, **but not within** `scale_gradient`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$logvec <- dlnorm(1:nrow(iris2)) #for a skewed distribution

ggplot(iris2, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, fill = logvec)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "navajowhite", mid = "red",
    high = "navyblue",
    na.value = "white",
    midpoint = mean(iris2$logvec),
    breaks = c(0, max(iris2$logvec))
  )
```

This kind of reproduces your example. (By the way, please use this as an example how to create a **minimal**! reproducible example 
[image]

Now transform the data.

```r
iris2 <-iris2 %>% mutate(logtrans = log(logvec))
hist(iris2$logtrans)
```

It actually worked:

[image]

Using the new vector, we can easily use this for a nice `scale_gradient`. However, the labels won't be quite the ones that you want - note in my examples, after log transform, all values remain negative, thus I have changed the breaks. For the labels, you need to rescale your values to a range between 0 and 1.

```r
ggplot(iris2, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, fill = logtrans)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "navajowhite", mid = "red",
    high = "navyblue",
    na.value = "white",
    midpoint = mean(iris2$logtrans),
    breaks = c(min(iris2$logtrans), max(iris2$logtrans)),
    labels = scales::rescale(c(min(iris2$logtrans), max(iris2$logtrans)))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The underlying data is highly skewed, so you need the log transform...

Comment: Perhaps log-transform the data in the dataframe. That way the color mapping (which I suspect always works linearly) would match the log scaling that you desire.

Comment: @Matt47 spot on. See one solution.